# SQL Selecting records sorted by growth over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a simple table that contains a daily summary of the sales volumes of a couple hundred thousand products. One row for each product and date, with whatever quantity was sold that day. Table format is:

`CREATE TABLE DAILYSALES (ID numeric IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ProductID numeric NOT NULL, XDate Date NOT NULL, QTY_SOLD int NOT NULL)`

A record will only be in the table if there were sales that day, so there are no records where QTY_SOLD is zero.

I need to figure out a way to query this data within a date range, say, the last 30 days, but sorted by a growth trend (products that showed the most growth over the period would be on top).

The difference in quantities sold is off the charts... some products sell 1,000+ units per day consistently, while others sell 1 or 2 or zero on an average day and just have a couple of spikes here and there.

In an ideal result set, a product that sold 10 units a day on the first of the month, and grew by one unit a day to 40 units per day at the end of the month would rank higher than a product that sold 1,000 units a day on average and grew to 2,000 by the end of the month (a 4X growth level vs 2X).

The trouble I keep running into is that products with little to no sales but a couple of big spikes near the end always end up on top. A product that goes from 1 sale at the start of the month, nothing all month, and then 20 sales on the last day would show up first with the above model -- that shouldn't outrank a product with steadier sales.

I'm not sure what the best way to write this query would be. I imagine some kind of subquery that factors in the number of records (ie; number of days with data) that exist in the result set should be a factor, but I'm not sure where to begin. Would appreciate any suggestions, in particular from those who work with large data sets and have had to do something similar.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, *and* your attempts will help us help you.

Comment: Yes, a few rows of sample data and the expected result will help us a lot to understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try some linear regression for this task. First identify the slope per article, then sort by slope descending. This way you should be able to identify the artricle qith the best growth. In the following example I have one article without sales, one with a constant size and one which starts at 0 and then growth in the following month:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
ArticleId int,
SoldDate date,
SoldQty int
)

;WITH cteDat AS(
  SELECT CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE) AS Dat
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, Dat)
    FROM cteDat
    WHERE Dat < '2020-12-31'
)
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 123 AS ArticleId, Dat AS SoldDate, 0 AS SoldQty
  FROM cteDat
UNION ALL
SELECT 456 AS ArticleId, Dat AS SoldDate, 100 AS SoldQty
  FROM cteDat
UNION ALL
SELECT 789 AS ArticleId, Dat AS SoldDate, 0 AS SoldQty
  FROM cteDat
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

UPDATE @t
  SET SoldQty = 50
  WHERE ArticleId = 789
    AND MONTH(SoldDate) > 7


;WITH cteRaw AS(
SELECT CAST(ArticleId AS FLOAT) AS ArticleId, CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), SoldDate, 112) AS FLOAT) DatSID, CAST(SoldQty AS FLOAT) AS SoldQty
  FROM @t
),
cteLinRegBase AS(
SELECT ArticleId
      ,COUNT(*) AS SampleSize
      ,SUM(DatSID) AS SumX
      ,SUM(SoldQty) AS SumY
      ,SUM(DatSID*DatSID) AS SumXX
      ,SUM(SoldQty*SoldQty) AS SumYY
      ,SUM(DatSID*SoldQty) AS SumXY
  FROM cteRaw
  GROUP BY ArticleId
)
SELECT ArticleId, CASE
                          WHEN SampleSize = 1 THEN 0 -- avoid divide by zero error
                          ELSE ( SampleSize * sumXY - sumX * sumY ) / ( SampleSize * sumXX - Power(sumX, 2) )
                        END
  FROM cteLinRegBase
```

However, instead of calculating with the date as number, you could also add a rownumber or whatever to represent the X axis.